# How I can render react components without jsx format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I try to make my "smart" popup component, which can open inside itself some components, but my realization isn't good, because it doesn't work.

I use redux approach for creating popup and action of opening my popup is able to get name of any component for rendering before popup will be open;

But I've some problem, after getting parameter, in our case it's **nameOfComponent**, I need to choose and render component with name **nameOfComponent**.

And my question now, how do It can render component from array?

```
// He's my components
import Login from '../Login/login.js';
import Logout from '../Logout/logout.js';


const popupContent = {
    Login : Login,
    logout: Logout
};

// My component 
class Popup extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate () {
        // for example
        const nameOfComponent = "Login";

        this.body = this.setBodyPopup(nameOfComponent);

        return true;
    }

    setBodyPopup(property){
         return popupContent[property];
     }


    render() {
        // I want to render some element from popupContent here
        <div>
            // <this.body /> // it's jsx format
            {this.body}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you are using `componentDidUpdate`, I think you can use constructor in this case  -  https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36027/

Comment: Because my popup can opening with another content, which passed throught props. I've single popup for spa.

Answer (score 6):

I added working example here [JSfiddle ReactJS](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36033/)

You dont have to use JSX. If you do, right way to do this is to use factory. You can also render regular HTML in the render method, as well as to use vanilla javascript in your code using curly braces.

Also to get I would recommend mapping and iterating through all your items in array and render them one by one in the render method

see example below:

```js
var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.name}, logged in</div>;
  }
});

// React with JSX
ReactDOM.render(<Login name="John" />,
  document.getElementById('containerJSX'));

// React without JSX
var Login = React.createFactory(Login);
ReactDOM.render(Login({ name: 'Tim' }),
  document.getElementById('containerNoJSX'));
```

Comment: `createFactory` has been deprecated. You can use [createElement](https://fr.react.dev/reference/react/createElement) now.

Answer (score 0):

As commentators suggest, you might want to specify `this.body` either in constructor or within the render method itself.

However, if I understand your intention correctly, you could just use `this.props.children` instead.
E.g.

```
<Popup><MyInnerComponent></Popup>
```

and in Popup `render` method

```
render() {
    <div>
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: In this case `this.body` will be undefined - so it is main problem, because if `this.body` was reference to Component it would work fine (`<this.body />`)

Comment: @Alexander That is true, I've overlooked that moment.

Answer (score 0):

React actually allows you to use variables with JSX syntax to instantiate components. You should actually be able to call `<this.body />` and have it work; **however** yours will not because you do not define `this.body` until the `componentDidUpdate` method, which means it will be undefined for the first render and break everything. I would suggest using local component state for this instead of `this.body` and making sure it is defined from the start.

At the very least, instantiate `this.body` in a constructor to some value:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.body = 'Login';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<this.body />` to render the component, as long as `this.body` has an actual value. Perhaps you just need:

```
render() {
    return <div>
        {this.body ? <this.body /> : null}
    </div>
}
```

With the example you gave, though, you can just put the contents of your `componentDidMount` in the `constructor` instead, because the constructor is invoked before the first render pass.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking at something like [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.body} />
```