# React: Creating A Component with ES6Class and rendering it without JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have just started to learn React and i am trying to render components which i create as from classes. I like this way very much since it is similar to Java the language that i started with.

So far i want to understand how i can create a class from scratch and just render it on the page.I have searched around the web a bit and found some examples like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222289/how-i-can-render-react-components-without-jsx-format) but they did not fit my situation because in that case , the user is using redux which i am not using. I also found several examples of rendering but they are not explicitly using classes.Could someone please show me how i can succesfully render the code to `react-container` i have here and explain it to me? Your help will be greatly appreciated !

```
class IngredientsList extends React.Component {

            renderListItem(ingredient, i) {
                return React.createElement("li", { key: i }, ingredient)
            }

            render() {
                return React.createElement("ul", { className: "ingredients" }, this.props.items.map(this.renderListItem))
            }

        }

        const myIngredients = new IngredientList();

        const items = ["1 lb Salmon", "1 cup pine nuts", "2 cups butter lettuce", "1 yellow squash", "1/2 cup Olive oil", "3 gloves of garlic"];

        const myList = myIngredients.renderListItem(items, 1);
        myIngredients.render();
```

```
<div id="react-container"></div>
```

so as you can see i have created the class, tried to initialize it and then use the render method but nothing displays.I suppose i have to somehow use this method here `document.getElementById('react-container')` to point where i want to render but i am not sure how to integrate that in my build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you never should call the `render` method on a component. React handles the rendering for you, which is a big part of why to use React in the first place.

You need to use [`ReactDOM.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) to mount your app into the DOM, and then React will manage the rendering of components and sub-components from there.

`ReactDOM.render` accepts two arguments. The first is the component, and the second is the actual DOM element where you want your app to be rendered on the page.

```js
class IngredientsList extends React.Component {
  renderListItem(ingredient, i) {
    return React.createElement("li", { key: i }, ingredient)
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement("ul", { className: "ingredients" }, this.props.items.map(this.renderListItem))
  }
}
        
const items = ["1 lb Salmon", "1 cup pine nuts", "2 cups butter lettuce", "1 yellow squash", "1/2 cup Olive oil", "3 gloves of garlic"];

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(IngredientsList, {items: items}), 
  document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works great. Could you please also explain this. Do i just need to pass the class name? i mean i don't need to instantiate anything and react takes care of the rest? also do i need to have a render method inside the class component i want to render? will this method be called by react automatically?

Comment: @helloApp Notice that it is **not** a class name (its not a string), it is a **reference** to a class (not an instance of the class). So yes, React will both instantiate the class, and call the `render` method on it. And yes you must name the method "render" so that React knows to call it.