# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at (index):452:25) react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

this is my simple react js component. I am making a build and trying to use it on my WordPress website.

I am getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at (index):452:25)
when I run the code in the backend. i tried various things from the internet but nothing worked. please help
//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

//

```
 const App = ({ message }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

wordpress hook

```
 function react_app_shortcode($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'message' => 'Default Message',
        ),
        $atts
    );
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div id="react-app"></div>
    <script>
        const rootElement = document.getElementById('react-app');
        const message = '<?php echo esc_js($atts['message']); ?>';
        ReactDOM.render(<App message={message} />, rootElement);
        console.log("code is working")
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('react_app', 'react_app_shortcode');
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<index message={message} />,` you're using JSX here. Consider not using JSX when it's put directly in the page.

Comment: what would be the right way can you tell me. from the shortcode I want to send an argument to my React component. because it will be dynamic. I just can't add HTML.

Comment: React Component and Their filename must be start using Capital Letter. https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#:~:text=React%20components%20are%20regular%20JavaScript%20functions%2C%20but%20their%20names%20must%20start%20with%20a%20capital%20letter%20or%20they%20won%E2%80%99t%20work!

Comment: @sahilatahar yes there are using. I just forget to change it when I post it. let me change it

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222289/how-i-can-render-react-components-without-jsx-format

Comment: @sahilatahar no. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: maybe that's not a good way to put React component. I deployed my build on netlify and it didn't gave any error